# C : Accessing contiguous array elements using a pointer returned by a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the following program, I get the output 
1
0
0
2130567168
11
2686668
7
2686916

whereas according to me the output must be 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

because the array elements are stored in contiguous memory locations and I am accessing those elements in a contiguous fashion.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *fun3();

int main(){
    int j, k;
    int *q = fun3();
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        printf("%d\t", *(q+j));
    }
}

int *fun3(){
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    return a;
}
```

Please suggest any problems in my code or my reasoning.Why am I getting this unusual behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Returning char\[\] Warning "returns address of local variable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872518/c-returning-char-warning-returns-address-of-local-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array `a` has automatic storage duration, which ends when the function `fun3()` returns.  This means it's not legal to access it after this point - doing so has undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of `int a[]` is limited to `fun3`, so you can not return it and expect it to stay valid.

Comment: If *scope* is the reason then @BLUEPIXY's answer would also exhibit the same behaviour; but it isn't.

Comment: @KingsIndian, @BryanOliver No, the `static` in @BLUEPIXY's answer actually means "store this on the heap", so it is persistent across calls to the function (in theory, I guess a compiler could allocate some heap storage and copy between heap and stack on each entry and exit to the function, but I suspect none actually do).

Comment: @Vatine They were referring to `scope` versus `lifetime`. And `static` doesn't mean "store this on the heap". "scope", "lifetime" and "static" have very specific meanings in this context.

Comment: @Andrei Yes, but unless the compiler takes extra steps to ensure that the pointer to the static member is, indeed, copied between heap and stack, a pointer to a lexically-scoped static variable function will be sensibly accessible from outside the function. And access to one that isn't won't be.

Comment: @Vatine actually such a `static` variable will in general just become global storage. It's name is just limited to the scope of `fun3`.

Comment: @BryanOlivier Yes, but we were (I believe) discussing if a pointer to the variable would sensibly point to storage accessible from outside the function.

Comment: @Vatine Ah, I understand. I sure hope it is, because otherwise a lot of code will break. But I'm going to look it up.

Comment: @Vatine Phew, it seems it is. See 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects ad 3 "... has _static storage duration_. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup". Ad 2 defines the pointer to such storage.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[]` of function `fun3` is local scope. scope of a is no longer valid if you get out of this function. It is one way it is because since an `auto` variable is storage class for example is to change the `static`.

```
int *fun3(){
    static int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    return a;
}
```